# How do I check all checkboxes on an HTML page with one click (Array of checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<form name="smform" id="smform" method="post" action="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="Check_All" onClick="Check(document.smform.check)"  >

     <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="blue_color"> Blue<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="green_color"> Green<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="orange_color"> Orange<br>
</form>
```

With the this JS:

```
function Check(chk)
    {
        if(document.smform.Check_All.checked){
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = true ;
        document.smform.Check_All.checked = true;
    }else{

        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false ;
        document.smform.Check_All.checked = false;
    }
}
```

And this this is working fine, I can select or deselect all checkboxes, but in order to post this as an ARRAY, my check boxes will have the `name="check[]"` like:

```
     <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="blue_color"> Blue<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="green_color"> Green<br>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="orange_color"> Orange<br>
```

But in this case my JS is not working. How can I adapt this JS so it works with `name="check[]"` ?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just dont use dot-notation, instead use square brackets and a string:

```
onClick="Check(document.smform['check[]'])"
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/5JCMS/

Answer (score 2):

you can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all checkboxes

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
Check(inputs);
    function Check(chk)
        {
            if(document.smform.Check_All.checked){
              for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++){
                if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
                    chk[i].checked = true ;
                }
               }
            document.smform.Check_All.checked = true;
        }else{

            for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++){
               if(inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
            chk[i].checked = false ;
             }
           }
            document.smform.Check_All.checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Use Jquery. You can add a class to all the checkboxes you wish to check

```
<input type='checkbox' class='autocheckable someOtherClass' />Blue
```

And then do as described here: [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Its seen as a bit of a cardinal sin round here to answer a question not taged `jQuery` with a jQuery answer.

Comment: There is JavaScript outside of jQuery

Comment: Even though, this gives an idea/suggests using classes in standard javascript and then calling the class to check the checkboxes, the OP can use this without jQuery.

Comment: 3 downvotes! Sheeesh.

Well Ok. I assume the poster is learning - no one coding for money in the real-world would do this without JQuery  ;-)